# Не монимаю вообщем, Python 3.9. Когда я напишу print('text'), Вводитсья текст. Но я напишу любое слово вводитсья на консоль. Помогите Пожалуйста

Tags: python

```
a = True
while (a == True):
    v = input()
    if (v == "print('", str, "')"):
        v = v.replace("print('", "")
        v = v.replace("')", "")
        print(v)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой результат вам нужен? Ваше "условие" в if всегда истинно, потому что результат его выполнения - непустой кортеж вида `(False, <class 'str'>, "')")` (первое - результат сравнения v и `"print('"`, потом все что вы перечислили через запятую)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем случаем if странная проверка которая всегда возвращает True.
Если правильно понял суть то Ваш код удобнее реализовать так:

```py
while True:
    v = input()
    if "print" in v: # Проверяем если ли слово "print" в v
        v = v.replace("print('", "")
        v = v.replace("')", "")
        print(v)
```

Пример того почему у вас ошибка:

```py
v = input()
if (v == "a", "b"):
    print("Верно")
```

Так как `(v == "a", "b")` является кортежем внутри которого вы делаете проверку но от этого он все равно не пустой а значит = `True`